# Reading a maze file composed of characters, and write to an array (java)

Tags: java, arrays, file, maze

I have a program attempting to read characters from a file and input them into an array. I'm still trying to attempt to grasp arrays in java.

```
    // Read the file describing the maze.
static void readMazeFile(String mazefile) throws FileNotFoundException {
    File themaze = new File(mazefile);
    Scanner text_reader = new Scanner(themaze);
    int height = text_reader.nextInt();
    int width = text_reader.nextInt();
    char[][] amaze = new char[((2 * height) + 1)][];
    for (int r = 0; r < height; r++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < width; c++) {
            char pos = text_reader.next().charAt(0);
            System.out.print(pos);
            amaze[r][c] = pos;

        }

    }

}

// Solve the maze.
static boolean solveMaze() {
    return true;
}
}
```

That is the code I'm currently working with, the input works well so I don't believe it is that, as I spent a ridiculous amount of time getting that to work. I tried to get the two for loops off Stack Overflow, but it seems my issue arises  from the amaze[r][c] = pos; line.

```
+Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at MazeSolver.readMazeFile(MazeSolver.java:81)
    at MazeSolver.main(MazeSolver.java:29)
```

Is the error I got. I'm honestly stuck, not sure where to go from here. The text file looks like this:

```
2 3
+-+-+-+
|S|   |
+ + + +
|   |E|
+-+-+-+
```

It reads the top two lines perfectly, so those are taken care of. I just need assistance getting the loops to read each line, and change lines once it is all read. Once thing I need to keep in mind is we are given 6 mazes, and not all are perfect squares/rectangles such as the one I gave as an example.

A point in the right direction would be awesome, thanks all.

Main() code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    if (handleArguments(args)) {
        mazefile = args[0];

        readMazeFile(mazefile);
        char[][] maze = new char[3][];
        maze[0] = new char[] { '+', '-', '+' };
        maze[1] = new char[] { '|', 'S', '|' };
        maze[2] = new char[] { '+', '-', '+' };
        DrawMaze.draw(height, width, maze, borderwidth, cellsize, sleeptime);

        if (solveMaze())
            System.out.println("Solved!");
        else
            System.out.println("Maze has no solution.");
    }
}
```

Comment: for (int r = 0; r <width ; r++) {
        for (int c = 0; c <height ; c++) {
            char pos = text_reader.next().charAt(0);
            System.out.print(pos);
            amaze[r][c] = pos;
        }
    }

Comment: Also check  char pos = text_reader.next().charAt(0);
In this statement check if text_reader.next() is returning null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, problem is second dimension size is missing.

**1st way**

```
//static declaration 

char[][] amaze = new char[((2 * height) + 1)][1];
```

**2nd Way**

```
//dynamic decalaration of second dimension

char[][] amaze = new char[((2 * height) + 1)][];
amaze[r]=new char[1];
amaze[r][c] = pos;
```

See [jaggedArray](http://www.java2s.com/Book/Java/0020__Language-Basics/Jagged_array.htm)

Comment: I tested this and I'm still receiving the same error. I was under the impression that only the first dimension is necessary, but the second does not need to be entered. I also did this because there will always be a consistent amount of rows, but not columns.

Comment: Added it up in the OP.